# Uploadify with HTTPS in Firefox not working

Tags: firefox, https, uploadify

I am facing the problem of uploadify with HTTPS in Firefox.

I am unable to upload the file via uploadify if I use https. But it works fine if I upload it via http in Firefox(3.6).

Uploads working fine in other browsers in http and https.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Hussain Cutpiecewala | eHussain

Answer (score 2):

Uploadify uses SWFUpload so check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789863/swfupload-on-https-not-working).

Basically you need an **official** certificate.